# Prompt Expansion ZSH nested truncation

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, macintosh

Currently, this is the format of my ZSH Prompt.  I have been reading over https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion to further understand truncation in zsh prompts, but I cannot figure out how to solve this nested truncation problem I am running into.

```bsh
export PROMPT="(%10>,,,>[%5>...>william%>>]hello%>>)"
```

gives

```
([wi...]hello)
```

when I want it to initially truncate the interior expression `%5>...>william%>>`
then take that truncated expression and pass it into the exteriior expression and truncate that.

i.e. I want the output

```
([wi...,,,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says that

> The part of the prompt string to be truncated runs to the end of the string, or to the end of the next enclosing group of the `%(` construct, **or to the next truncation encountered at the same grouping level** (i.e. truncations inside a `%(` are separate), which ever comes first. In particular, a truncation with argument zero (e.g., `%<<`) marks the end of the range of the string to be truncated while turning off truncation from there on.

That is, they don't nest on the same level: the first `%>>` stops truncation and the second does nothing since truncation isn't active any more there.

But you can nest them with `%(...)`.

```
PROMPT='%12>#>12[%(0l,%5>#>abcefghijk,)]345678%>> end$ '
```

gives

```
12[abce#]34# end$
```

The inner part is `abcefghijk`, it's truncated to five characters, and wrapped in `[]`, and then the `12[abce#]345678` gets truncated to 12 characters.